# Last Stream not finished in MariaDB on BlueMix Liberty Profile (Hibernate)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I am getting a Last stream not finished in MariaDB on BlueMix. This app works OK locally with MySQL and was recently working ok too. It started failing only for LONGTEXT data types but now fails even for VARCHAR(255):

```
2016-02-08T12:17:16.337+0100[App/0]OUTHibernate: insert into Property (value, name) values (?, ?)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.355+0100[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.markRollbackOnly(CMTTransaction.java:131)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.355+0100[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:118)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.355+0100[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.setRollbackOnly(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:138)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.servlet.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:40)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at com.cogniapi.jsf.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:32)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.355+0100[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.application.ejb.EJSLocalNSGApplicationManagerBean_04c55490.setProperty(EJSLocalNSGApplicationManagerBean_04c55490.java)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.355+0100[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:326)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.servlet.ServengineWebFilter.doFilter(ServengineWebFilter.java:147)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.355+0100[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter$1.invoke(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:175)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.355+0100[App/0]ERR at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.beforeCompletion(Unknown Source)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at com.ibm.ws.jtaextensions.SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackWrapper.java:71)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.356+0100[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.application.ApplicationPreferencesAdminView.store(ApplicationPreferencesAdminView.java:51)
     2016-02-08T12:17:16.355+0100[App/0]ERR[ERROR ] WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2016-02-08T12:51:27.640+0100[App/0]OUT[AUDIT ] J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource jdbc/CogniAPIDS. The exception is: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not send query: Last stream not finished:org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Could not send query: Last stream not finished:java.io.IOException: Last stream not finished
2016-02-08T12:51:27.668+0100[App/0]OUT[INFO ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Could not send query: Last stream not finished com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl.end 438" at ffdc_16.02.08_12.51.27.0.log
2016-02-08T12:51:27.671+0100[App/0]ERR[ERROR ] DSRA0302E: XAException occurred. Error code is: UNKNOWN XA EXCEPTION CODE (0). Exception is: Could not send query: Last stream not finished
2016-02-08T12:51:27.671+0100[App/0]ERR[ERROR ] DSRA0304E: XAException occurred. XAException contents and details are: The cause is : null.
2016-02-08T12:51:27.933+0100[App/0]OUT[INFO ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Could not send query: Last stream not finished com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.end 417" at ffdc_16.02.08_12.51.27.1.log
2016-02-08T12:51:27.973+0100[App/0]OUT[INFO ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Could not send query: Last stream not finished com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.JTAXAResourceImpl.end 307" at ffdc_16.02.08_12.51.27.2.log
2016-02-08T12:51:27.996+0100[App/0]OUT[INFO ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Could not send query: Last stream not finished com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.sendEnd 1157" at ffdc_16.02.08_12.51.27.3.log
2016-02-08T12:51:28.011+0100[App/0]OUT[INFO ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not send query: Last stream not finished com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.destroy 1005" at ffdc_16.02.08_12.51.27.4.log
```

Comment: It looks like one of your services is not compatible with the rest of your environment:  `[ERROR ] WTRN0074E: Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`  can you post some of the FFDC's that might have more details on what is trying to invoke this operation that is not supported?

Comment: Every insert operation is throwing this error. I deleted MariaDB and replaced with PostgreSQL, also in Bluemix, and the app is working OK now. Something has happened with that MariaDB boilerplate in Bluemix. We haven't been able to reproduce the error locally with MySQL or MariaDB. Anyway, it has been the perfect excuse to start working with PostgreSQL. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this MariaDB boilerplate? We would like to review it.

Comment: I use the standard MySQL/MariaDB one, provided by IBM... that's the one in the "Experimental" link you can see in the bottom of the services list when you select Beta.